# Showing a specific Route component in full screen

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a react application where I have many routes, with all routes specific components rendering inside a layout, which have header, footer and navigation all common. But on a specific page i want to render only that component, hiding all header and navigation. Here is my main app page:

```
<BrowserRouter>
<div className="app">
    <Route exact path="/fullscreen" component={() => <FullScreenComponent />} />
    <Header />
    <div className="container">
        <Route exact path={routes.LANDING} component={() => <LandingPage />} />
        <Route exact path={routes.SIGN_UP} component={() => <SignUpPage />} />
        <Route exact path={routes.SIGN_IN} component={() => <SignInPage />} />
        <Route exact path={routes.PASSWORD_FORGET} component={() => <PasswordForgetPage />} />
        <Route exact path={routes.HOME} component={() => <HomePage />} />
    </div>
    <Footer />
</div>
```

Here I want to show FullScreenComponent only on the page, but it is also showing header and footer in the bottom of the page. I want to hide them. I don't want to show them as full screen on the browser, not on the monitor. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to render only the route, then there must be a boolean or a conditional statement to hide others from rendering :)

react-router offers props.location.pathname to get the current pathanme so =>

```
<div className="app">
    {props.location.pathname==="/fullscreen"? 
    <Route exact path="/fullscreen" component={() => <FullScreenComponent />} /> :(
    <>
    <Header />
    <div className="container">
        <Route exact path={routes.LANDING} component={() => <LandingPage />} />
        <Route exact path={routes.SIGN_UP} component={() => <SignUpPage />} />
        <Route exact path={routes.SIGN_IN} component={() => <SignInPage />} />
        <Route exact path={routes.PASSWORD_FORGET} component={() => <PasswordForgetPage />} />
        <Route exact path={routes.HOME} component={() => <HomePage />} />
    </div>
    <Footer />
    </>)
</div>
```